# Workarounds for lack of varargs in Erlang

Tags: erlang, variadic-functions, function-composition

Completely new to Erlang. I'm trying to define some functions for function composition, such as `compose`, `juxt` and `pipe` but running into the fact that Erlang doesn't have (to my knowledge) varargs so it's difficult to write just one version of such functions that will work for all inputs.

So far my best idea is to hardcode functions of different arities up to a reasonable number, as well as providing a version that takes a list for anything bigger, like this:

```
pipe (X, Fs) when is_list(Fs) -> lists:foldl(fun (F, Acc) -> F(Acc) end, X, Fs);
pipe (X, F) -> F(X).
pipe (X, F, G) -> G(F(X)).
pipe (X, F, G, H) -> H(G(F(X))).
pipe (X, F, G, H, I) -> I(H(G(F(X)))).
pipe (X, F, G, H, I, J) -> J(I(H(G(F(X))))).
pipe (X, F, G, H, I, J, K) -> K(J(I(H(G(F(X)))))).
pipe (X, F, G, H, I, J, K, L) -> L(K(J(I(H(G(F(X))))))).
```

which works, but I'm curious if there's a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that Erlang functions are uniquely identified by `Name/Arity`; `io:format/1` and `io:format/2`, for instance, are two *different* functions. Hence, variadic functions simply don't fit into Erlang.

The cleanest solution is probably what you suggested. Another option is to write a custom [parse](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_id_trans.html) [transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416192/is-there-a-good-complete-tutorial-on-erlang-parse-transforms-available) (a module that rewrites the AST after parsing but before compilation) to catch and transform calls to the specific functions you want, letting others pass through unmolested. The transform could intercept calls like `pipe(A1, A2, A3, ..., An)` and rewrite them to `pipe([A1, A2, A3, ..., An])`.

Be warned though: Parse transforms can be difficult to get right, and they must be explicitly referenced in every module that needs to use the features they provide. An example of parse transforms put to good use is Basho's [Lager](https://github.com/basho/lager) logging library.

Comment: Thanks, parse transforms sound interesting, I will take a look.

Comment: If you do go down the parse transform route, remember that with great power comes great responsibility.

Comment: Looking at it I doubt I will, I think my hard-coded solution will be enough to cover most cases and it's hard to justify something like parse transforms for edge cases.. but they look interesting to learn about.

Comment: https://github.com/uwiger/parse_trans is helpful if you go down the parse transform route

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why the list notation is not good for you, because it gives a very short and easy implementation, similar to the io:format/2.

```
pipe (X, Fs) when is_list(Fs) -> lists:foldl(fun (F, Acc) -> F(Acc) end, X, Fs).
fibnext([A,B]) -> [A+B,A].


1> F = fun(X) -> my_module:fibnext(X) end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.82930912>
2> my_module:pipe([1,1],lists:duplicate(12,F)).      
[377,233]
3>
```